# How to know my Google Cloud Identity from the command line?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, authorization, amazon-iam, google-iam

I'm running Python code on my computer that makes calls to Google Cloud Platform. I'm trying to know if my application is using my own credentials or service account keys to get authorizations on GCP.

On AWS, I could use `aws sts get-caller-identity` to know who the caller is (IAM user or IAM role).

Is there a GCP equivalent, something like `gcloud whoami`, that I could run from the command line or from my Python code itself to know the identity used by my application?

Comment: check this https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/auth/application-default/print-access-token  . Command <b> curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "access_token=$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo </b> gives you json with details

Comment: gcloud auth list command can be helpful. 
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/list

Comment: Thanks for your answers! @Arkon88, special thanks for the method you propose, I was not aware of it! :) Your code snippet explicitly uses the `application-default` token to get metadata from it, how am I sure that this corresponds to the identity used by my application? In my example, the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable is set and points to a service account key: how do I know which identity (application-default or service-account) is used by my Python code? :)

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

If the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set, ADC uses the service account key or configuration file that the variable points to.

If the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS isn't set, ADC uses the service account that is attached to the resource that is running your code.

This service account might be a default service account provided by Compute Engine, Google Kubernetes Engine, App Engine, Cloud Run, or Cloud Functions. It might also be a user-managed service account that you created.

Comment: Thanks @Arkon88! Ideally, I'd like to be able to verify it using an equivalent of whoami command :/ 
My problem here is that my app runs correctly from a jupyter notebook but faces permission errors when running from a container even though it uses the same service account key (passed as volume and specified from the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`env variable)
So I was thinking something must be overwriting this when running on the jupyter notebook

Comment: strange it should work. it is possible that in container value is not set. print it out (GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS ) using python code. it should be empty. Check permissions on your service key file and add EXPORT GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS statement in shell so every child process can use it as well

Comment: Thanks again for your help @Arkon88!
Actually the env variable is specified from the docker-compose file `environment` section and it is well reached by my Python code. I also checked that the Python code has read access to the service account json file and it does.
The Python code runs behind Flask and Gunicorn so I suspect there might be something happening in between.
I'll post something when I find the root cause or a solution to my problem :/

Answer (score 6):

Use the command `gcloud auth list` in your cli to view the active credentials account.

Comment: Hello @bilcy, thanks for your answer!
Upvoting as this answer will be useful to some people but I'd need to know with more certainty which principal is making the calls on my behalf when I run commands: is it my own account? is it a service account, and which one? Also, ideally, the answer would be usable from inside a container